# Flutter - Change Stepper - Step Color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, stepper

Is there a way to change the color of the Steps without creating a custom Stepper?
the current step is blue.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Step-class.html

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart

Comment: Thank you , so its using the primaryColor of the material app theme.  :)

Comment: Submitted a bug here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57364 the other buttons are using accentColor as button background...

Answer (score 11):

Wrap your stepper in a Theme Widget.

```
body: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
                  accentColor: Colors.orange,
                  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
                  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                    primary: Colors.orange
                  )
                ),
    child: Stepper(
       steps: []
    ))
```

It will change the **index** color of the stepper as well as the **CONTINUE** button color to orange(Set the color as per your own requirement).

Answer (score 10):

In April 2022 these properties work

1. Light theme - `primary` - the active state, `primary.withOpacity(0.38)` will be used for the disabled state.
2. Dark theme - `secondary` - the active state, `background` - the disabled state.

```
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          canvasColor: Colors.yellow,
          colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
                primary: Colors.green,
                background: Colors.red,
                secondary: Colors.green,
              ),
        ),
        child: Stepper(
```

The result in the dark mode.

[image]

Comment: How to change disabled state color in light theme?

Comment: I afraid it is not possible. I've submitted the issue 2 weeks ago, you can vote to speed up the fixes. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102558

Comment: @awaik how would you change the color of the icons and number within the circles, like the black tick mark to white and the 3 from white to black

Comment: You can't
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102558 
you can vote for this issue, for speed up the fix.

Answer (score 5):

The color of the steps depends on `ColorScheme.primary` color, to change it you have to wrap `Stepper` with `Theme` and in `ThemeData` add colorScheme property like this:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(primary: yourColor),
              ),
  child: Stepper(...),
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

As of flutter version 1.22.0, the stepper button colors are determined by `ThemeData.colorScheme` instead of `ThemeData.primaryColor`.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Flutter package material stepper code you will see that the step's circular icon/indicator depends on whether it is active or not.

It will use your `colorScheme.primary` color when active in light mode, or your `colorScheme.secondary` colour when active in dark mode.

When a step is not the currently active one, it will use either:

Light Mode: Your `colorScheme.onSurface` value with an opacity of 0.38
Dark Mode: Your `colorScheme.background` colour

So, you can use a custom theme wrapped around your stepper to override your default theme; or, use the stepper's active state to control the current step's colour as intended by the widget.

Flutter Stepper `_circleColor` method:

```dart
Color _circleColor(int index) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    if (!_isDark()) {
      return widget.steps[index].isActive ? colorScheme.primary : colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38);
    } else {
      return widget.steps[index].isActive ? colorScheme.secondary : colorScheme.background;
    }
  }
```

Example implementation in light mode :

```dart
 Theme(
         data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                    colorScheme: Theme.of(context)
                              .colorScheme
                              .copyWith(onSurface: Colors.red.shade200,
primary: Colors.red)),
                      child: Stepper());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + right-click on Step (it takes you to Stepper.dart file)
here you can find all the config and colors for the step.
for me changed the continue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMO3j.png) flat button by changing this code.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Your Existing Theme Colors

For some reason, stepper does not inherit your main `MaterialApp()`'s theme. But you can wrap your `Stepper()` widget with `Theme()` and use your primary theme's colors anyways.

Assuming you're using the `theme` property of your `MaterialApp()`, and that you've set the `colorScheme` property with both `primary` and `secondary` colors. *(as of Flutter 2.5, accentColor is officially deprecated)*

A basic `colorScheme` example for `ThemeData()`:

```dart
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(primary: Colors.green, secondary: Colors.lightGreen),
```

To apply this colorScheme to your `Stepper()` widget, you can copy your primary theme using `Theme.of(context)`.

```dart
Container(
  child: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context),
    child: Stepper(
      ...
    ),
  ),
),
```

### For Different Colors

Just create the new colorscheme here on the `data` property, the same way you'd apply the `ThemeData()` to your `MaterialApp()`'s `theme` property.

#### Reference

- [ThemeData Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)
- [ColorScheme Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieved this:

```
body: Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    accentColor: Colors.blueAccent
  ),
  child: Stepper(
    steps: []
  ),
)
```

Basically wrap your stepper in a Theme widget and set the `accentColor` of `ThemeData` to your desired color.

Comment: Didn't work for me, only the 'Continue' color changed not the indexes of Stepper;

Comment: If you don't want the above code to override all your styles use `ThemeData.of(context).copyWith()`.

Comment: not working!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your stepper in a Theme Widget

```
body: Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent
  ),
  child: Stepper(
    steps: []
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in flutter where color is hardcoded for stepper icons and numbers as per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102558.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connectorColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper/connectorColor.html) for Stepper line color

```
Material(
        color: lightGreen,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(15))),
        elevation: 1,
        child: Stepper(
          currentStep: 2,
          connectorThickness: 5,
          controlsBuilder: (context, details) {
            return Container();
          },
          steps: steps,
          connectorColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) =>  Color.fromRGBO(0, 178, 187, 1)[enter image description here][1]),
        ),
      ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKq6a.png)

Answer (score -1):

```html
 In Flutter 2 just follow this :
 
 Theme(
      data: ThemeData(colorScheme:          ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith( primary: Color(0xfffada36),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

In flutter 2 just follow this:
Theme(
data: ThemeData(
colorScheme:
ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
primary: Color(0xfffada36),
),
),

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).